# MySQL UPDATE QUERY Duplication error

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Let's see if I can nail down the question because it's pretty complex to my mid-level MySQL skills.

PROBLEM:

I have a need to update some data in one of my DB tables. The problem is the data I am updating is tied to more than one row.

id          mailing_list_id          subscriber_id

9031                    51                    81053

9112                    52                    81053

13535                  71                    81053

I need to update mailing_list_id 52 and rename it 51 but the subscriber_id already exists with mailing_list_id of 51 so I want to skip that record during my update.

When I use the following:

UPDATE subscriptions SET mailing_list_id = 51 WHERE mailing_list_id = 52;

I get an error saying there is a duplicate entry.

What I need to do is ignore duplicates in my query but I don't know how to write the query. Any help would be appreciated.

I need to add something to my query to skip the rows where the subscriber id already has a mailing list id # the same as the one I am trying to change it to. Not sure if that makes sense or if at this point I am rambling. I know what I want to do I just don't know the query syntax or method to make it happen.

Comment: Do you have a Database Admin you're working with? The error message you're getting indicates to me that there's some kind of restriction already on the table that doesn't allow duplicate mailing_list_id's. If that's the case, no T-SQL syntax is going to help you. On a side note, why are you doing this anyway?

Answer (score 2):

What field mailing_list_id have a index (unique or primary)? if yes so you cannot change which the data exists in other row.

The solution is:
1. You remove extra key(unique or primary) in field mailing_list_id.
2. Or you create new table and remove your table, after you remove table subscription, run query in below to create new table subscription.

```
CREATE TABLE subscriptions (
     id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
     mailing_list_id INT(11),
     subscriber_id INT(11)
);
```

Comment: the mailing_list_id is not a primary key. I have another field, which i left out of the original question that contains a generic id field with auto increment. I used the first recommendation above in a test table and it ignored the duplicate results changing all the other ones and then left me with the duplicates which I subsequently was able to remove from the table. I know it is not the greatest solution but lacking other ideas I have chosen to move forward with that solution. Thank you AlienWebguy and Andi Unpam for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't recommend this as a permanent solution, this should get rid of your errors so you can get things working while you plan out a better schema - unique keys, `REPLACE INTO`, etc.

```
UPDATE IGNORE subscriptions SET mailing_list_id = 51 WHERE mailing_list_id = 52;
```

Comment: Tend to agree, sounds like `REPLACE INTO` should be the way to go, though not ideal.